# Calculating BMR with HealthKit data in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, healthkit

Trying to transfer formulas that calculate a user's BMR and TDEE. These are pretty basic formulas in terms of calculations but I am having a hard time converting the data from HealthKit through Xcode and converting it into workable values that I can run basic formulas with.

The formula I am aiming to implement looks like this:

```
10 * ('Weight' * .45) + 6.25 * ('Height' * 2.54) - 5 * 'Age' + 5
```

This is the code I've managed to develop so far and I am able to request access to HealthKit through the App Simulator. I'm just not sure how to convert `HKObjectType.quantityType` into a working integer.

```swift
import UIKit
import HealthKit

let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func accessHK(_ sender: Any) {
    if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
      let share = Set([HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass) !,
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyFatPercentage) !,
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height) !
      ])
      let read = Set([HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass) !,
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyFatPercentage) !,
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height) !
      ])
      healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: share, read: read) {
        (chk, error) in
        if (chk) {
          print("permission granted")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax of your formula is ambiguous.  Do you mean `10 * ('Weight' * .45) + 6.25 * ('Height' * 2.54) - 5 * 'Age' + 5` ?

Comment: @Christophe yes that is correct!